# Go back to calling website

Tags: php, javascript, firefox, session-cookies

after searching (and testing) a way to offer a kind of **go-back** button I am asking that question here (maybe there is an easy solution).

I have a description about orienteering on my website (5 pages): http://www.uhebeisen.net/o-def/o-definition_ge.php

There are many websites from abroad having a link to this pages. Now I'd like to get their URL if a websurfer is entering my pages. Then I can place a button go-back to my navigation list that brings him back to his page from where he clicked the link to my description-pages.

I've seen solutions using javascript:history.go(-1) or $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] with PHP but problem is that a websurfer can move around my pages and if finishing his reading from any page should be provided with his (calling) URL, e.g. the one of his University.

So I need to catch his URL and store it in a safe place until he decides to leave. And if he returns to the starting page while surfing on my pages his URL shouldn't be overwritten.
Since I do not program - just copy&paste and try to understand what happens. Any suggestion on how this can be done is welcome.

---

thank you George, that one worked
I wasn't aware to place the  **session_start** at the very beginning of the file that's why I get the two warnings.
While testing this function I found that the session variables were not always cleared by the browser. Especially with Firefox, it keeps the calling URL almost forever (WinXP, FF 5.x) whereas Firefox 5 on the Mac, Safari (Mac) and Camino (Mac) work as expected: after restarting the program I can test successfully with another website.

Does Firefox have different setting possibilities in regard of sessions than other browsers?

Comment: Seems that you are answering your own question: store the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in a session, cookie or database.

Answer (score 3):

You should store $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in the user's session upon arrival. Using this method, the value won't be overritten when the user browses within your site.

```
session_start();
if ( !isset( $_SESSION['referrer'] ) ) {
    if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ) { // Because not all browsers set this
        $_SESSION['referrer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer George, I've just put that code in front of my page. Now I am given two warnings: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hebeisen/public_html/o-def/o-definition_ge.php:1) in /home/hebeisen/public_html/o-def/o-definition_ge.php on line 3

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/hebeisen/public_html/o-def/o-definition_ge.php:1) in /home/hebeisen/public_html/o-def/o-definition_ge.php on line 3

Comment: Hi George, I used this function and placed it into my WordPress footer.php which renders across the entire domain. I echoed `$_SESSION['referrer']` and I see the URL is changing as I browse within my site. What can I change or check to keep the original referrer in the variable?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to store somewhere (perhaps in a cookie or session, which easy to do with your PHP page) the page they're coming from, but **only if** that page is not on your website's domain.  This would require some if-statements to set the cookie/session value appropriately, but it can be done relatively easily using particular parts of the referrer variable.  There is probably a more efficient way to store this, but this is one that jumps to mind right away.

EDIT:  I highly recommend George's solution, much better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a session?

```
session_start();

if( !isset($_SESSION['refer']) )
{
    $_SESSION['refer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

then, once your ready to make the button, set the link to $_SESSION['refer'].

Answer (score 0):

In my past projects I usually stores the redirect url following this process:

1. search for a query string parameter url (www.yoursite.com/?redirect_url=my_encoded_url)
2. If search at point 1 doesn't return any results, then I checks for the HTTP_REFERER

In both cases, I stores that value in a SESSION variable after verified that the url belongs to my site's domain.